# Using Twython to 'favorite' a tweet

Tags: api, twitter, twython, favorite

I'm trying to 'favorite' a tweet using Twython given that I know the tweet's ID, as described in "https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1" under the "POST favorites/create" section.

There seams to be a lot of documentation on how to search, update status, etc using Twython but I have not been able to find documentation on how to use the rest of the Twitter API using Twython (other than the search, get_home_timeline, and update_status methods).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me find documentation to use all of Twitter's API methods with Twython, more specifically how to "favorite"

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a favorite function available. Once you retrieve a tweet with it's informations, you should be able to retweet it using `Twython.create_favorite`:

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET
                  OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

#obtain the id of tweet you want to favorite
...
tweet_id = xxx
#done obtaining it

twitter.create_favorite(id=tweet_id)
```

Source: [Twython 3.1.1 Documentation](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#twython.Twython.create_favorite)